Pandas - Percentage from total in pivot table
I used to tackle this kind of thing reasonably quickly within DAX, but being new to pandas, I have been stuck for a while on this:
I am trying to output a pivot table showing the % of visa sales per month (columns) and per city (rows).
Here is the output I am looking for:
              Jan        Feb                     
London  50.055991  56.435644
Paris   15.119760  67.170191

I've tried various pivot tables and group-by functions, which got me so close and yet so far from what I need. I'm just used to creating "measures" in Excel that I can add to the pivot table like a regular dimension or fact.
Reproducible input:
data = {'Month': {0: 'Jan',
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Jan',
  3: 'Jan',
  4: 'Feb',
  5: 'Feb',
  6: 'Feb',
  7: 'Feb',
  8: 'Feb'},
 'City': {0: 'Paris',
  1: 'Paris',
  2: 'London',
  3: 'London',
  4: 'Paris',
  5: 'Paris',
  6: 'London',
  7: 'London',
  8: 'Paris'},
 'Card': {0: 'Visa',
  1: 'MasterCard',
  2: 'Visa',
  3: 'MasterCard',
  4: 'Visa',
  5: 'MasterCard',
  6: 'Visa',
  7: 'MasterCard',
  8: 'Visa'},
 ' Amount ': {0: ' $101 ',
  1: ' $567 ',
  2: ' $447 ',
  3: ' $446 ',
  4: ' $926 ',
  5: ' $652 ',
  6: ' $114 ',
  7: ' $88 ',
  8: ' $408 '}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df


Pls post desired output example

Hey @gtomer, I just edited my post with the expected outcome. Thanks

@ouroboros1 where do the visa/(visa+MC) happen in your code?

@Maximuluss: see the edit to my answer: the Visa/(Visa + MasterCard) is done by setting normalize.

Using a pivot_table, pipe to compute the ratio, and unstack to reshape:
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.strip(' $'))

out = (df
   .pivot_table(index=['Month', 'City'], columns='Card',
                values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
   .pipe(lambda x: x['Visa']/x.sum(axis=1)*100)
   .unstack('Month')
)

Output:
Month         Feb        Jan
City                        
London  56.435644  50.055991
Paris   67.170191  15.119760

To sort the months:
from calendar import month_abbr

months = {m:i for i, m in enumerate(month_abbr)}

df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.strip(' $'))

out = (df
   .pivot_table(index=['Month', 'City'], columns='Card',
                values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
   .pipe(lambda x: x['Visa']/x.sum(axis=1)*100)
   .unstack('Month').sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map(months))
)

Output:
Month         Jan        Feb
City                        
London  50.055991  56.435644
Paris   15.119760  67.170191


You can use pd.crosstab for this, chaining df.stack to move column level 'City' to the index, and df.loc to select only 'Visa' (and the columns in the desired order), and df.mul to multiply by 100.
# first turn your `' Amount ' column into `integers`
df[' Amount '] = df[' Amount '].str.replace('$', '').astype(int)

out = (
    pd.crosstab(
        index=df['Card'], 
        columns=[df['City'], df['Month']], 
        values=df[' Amount '], 
        aggfunc='sum', 
        normalize='columns'
    )
    .stack(level='City', future_stack=True)
    .loc['Visa', ['Jan','Feb']]
    .mul(100)
)

Output
out

Month         Jan        Feb
City                        
London  50.055991  56.435644
Paris   15.119760  67.170191


Edit. in response to the OP's question: where does Visa/(Visa + MasterCard) happen with pd.crosstab?
As per the docs, setting normalize will "[divide] all values by the sum of values". In this particular case, we pass 'columns' to normalize over each combination of 'City' and 'Month'.
I.e., the intermediate result without normalize would be:
(
    pd.crosstab(
        index=df['Card'], 
        columns=[df['City'], df['Month']], 
        values=df[' Amount '], 
        aggfunc='sum'
    )
)

City       London      Paris     
Month         Feb  Jan   Feb  Jan
Card                             
MasterCard     88  446   652  567
Visa          114  447  1334  101

With normalize='columns':
City          London              Paris          
Month            Feb      Jan       Feb       Jan
Card                                             
MasterCard  0.435644  0.49944  0.328298  0.848802
Visa        0.564356  0.50056  0.671702  0.151198

E.g., for Visa (row) and ('London', 'Feb') (column) we are getting 114/(88+114) = 0.564356. The rest of the above code only alters the shape/presentation of the result.

As I understand from your explanation you want to check visa payment % for each city or compare with visa - mastercard comparison percentage.
For the first one. Firstly, convert Amount column to numeric. So, for that I remove "$" sign from your data. After that, filter df for Visa transactions. Then, used group_by for  Month and City and calculate the total Visa sales for each month. Finally, pivot the table to have Month as columns and City as rows. In the last part removed Month label from table with     pivot_table.columns.name = None
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace('$', '',regex=True).str.strip().astype(float)

visa_df = df[df['Card'] == 'Visa']

grouped = visa_df.groupby(['Month', 'City']).agg({'Amount': 'sum'})

grouped['% of Visa Sales'] = grouped.groupby('Month', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x / x.sum() * 100)
grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)

pivot_table = grouped.pivot(index='City', columns='Month', values='% of Visa Sales')

pivot_table.columns.name = None

Output is like that :
              Feb        Jan
City
London   7.872928  81.569343
Paris   92.127072  18.430657

For Solution to what I understand visa - master compare.
Steps for that solution:



use group_by to group by Month, City, and Card and calculate
total sales for each month city and type of card.

used pivot_table to get desired table.

Calculate the percentage of Visa sales compared to total sales
for each city within each month and select only the required columns




Final code is like that .
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace('$', '',regex=True).str.strip().astype(float)

visa_master_df = df[df['Card'].isin(['Visa', 'MasterCard'])]

grouped = visa_master_df.groupby(['Month', 'City', 'Card']).agg({'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index()

print(grouped)

pivot_table = grouped.pivot_table(index=['City'], columns=['Month', 'Card'], values='Amount', fill_value=0)

for month in ['Jan', 'Feb']:
    pivot_table[('% of Visa Sales', month)] = (pivot_table[(month, 'Visa')] / (pivot_table[(month, 'Visa')] + pivot_table[(month, 'MasterCard')])) * 100

result = pivot_table[[('% of Visa Sales', 'Jan'), ('% of Visa Sales', 'Feb')]].round(2)
result.columns = ['Jan', 'Feb']
print(result)

Output is like
          Jan    Feb
City
London  50.06  56.44
Paris   15.12  67.17


The second one works!
